# PHP Extending Class one Folder Back

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a base abstract class, say `Base.php` located at `/lib/Helper/Base.php`. Now, I have another class, say `Awesome.php` located at `/lib/Helper/Awesome/Awesome.php`, and this class needs to extend `Base`.

I have defined my namespaces as follows:

**Base.php**

```
<?php namespace Helper;

abstract class Base
{

}
```

**Awesome.php**

```
<?php namespace Helper\Awesome;

class Awesome extends Base
{

}
```

Right now, this says that class `Base` was not found. I tried to use `require_once` and/or `include` to the path of `Base.php` and they also didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your 2 classes are in different namespaces.  Try `class Awesome extends Helper\Base`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I did. Now it says `Class 'Helper\\Awesome\\Helper\\Base' not found`. If I use `Helper\Base` doesn't that extend the namespace I have defined?

Comment: I had a feeling it'd do that.  I really mean to post `class Awesome extends \Helper\Base`.  The leading slash should make it look starting from the root.  You might still need to `include` the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including the file, and that is the right thing to do. But you are also using
namespaces.

the namespace is not a folder, that means the namespace 'Helper' is not a folder but a logical hierarchy. In order to use the class `Base` in he **logical** namespace `Helper` the `Awesome` class needs to extend the Base class with the full logical path i.e. `\Helper\Base`.

```
    namespace Helper\Awesome;

class Awesome extends \Helper\Base {

}
```

or use the `use/as` keyword instead (like c# `using` statement) .

```
  namespace Helper\Awesome;
use \Helper\Base as Base;
class Awesome extends Base
{

}
```

more information can be fount at the php.net site. 
here is a direct reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: That did the trick! I still had to `include` as suggested by @RocketHazmat for it to work though

Comment: Remember, the ` \ ` at the beginning of the namespace (when using the logical path, not on declaration) is important. If you forget it and try to do `class x extends a\b\c` and you have declared `namespace x\y\z` at the top you are trying to access `\x\y\z\a\b\c` (v.s. with the ` \ ` that is referring to `\a\b\c`).